# c# property with and without underlying field

Tags: c#, properties, default-value

I have a readonly property which returns a string, say "my string", I am confused now by the following two methods:

(1)

```
 public string MyProperty
    {
       get 
       {
           return "my string"
        }
     }
```

(2)

```
private string myString = "my string";

public string MyProperty
{
   get
   {
        return myString;
   }
 }
```

so in other places of my code, if I use, say

```
 string b = MyProperty;  // b should be "my string"
```

I would like to ask whether these two ways are both correct? or which one is preferred to the other?  Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: It depends if your going to be modifying mystring inside the class. if not, just use a const. if you are changing in the class, I'd say option 2 is the right way

Comment: Both will work and neither is "more correct". Although I would use a `static readonly string` in the 2nd example - unless it is allowed/meant to be changed from elsewhere in which the 1st case isn't even comparable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, because the main purpose of properties in OOP is to hide implementation details the prefer way to do it is using option 2...using a backing field. So, syntactically, both approaches are correct, but design-wise, approach 2 is the correct way to do it

Comment: There is no evidence provided in this response to support "design-wise, approach 2 is the correct way". This is because it is the *Property itself* that hides the implementation details - a feature which is seen in *both* approaches. (Notably, the implementation between the approaches *is* already interchangeable.)

Comment: well, what happens if we could add a bit of context and state to the parent class? Notably, the implementation between both approaches will no longer be interchangeable. So, design-wise....you know the rest

Comment: No, I don't know the rest. In fact, from the context given, the OP is merely asking about using a variable vs. returning a string directly. If the OP needs to do something else - who knows what, say, return a random string - then the implementation would be different than either #1 or #2 yet *the ABI was not changed*. As such, there is *no* evidence supporting #2 is better or "correct".

Comment: ok, so basically, if according to you design-wise is not the correct way to go. I guess it's also valid to state that we don't need interfaces when there's only one concrete object implementing it. Or even better, I could add a third approach to the question. Why would even be bothered to use properties when a public field will work...`public string myString = "my string";` or even a public constant? That's even a better approach, isnt it?

Comment: I've not said which [of the given property implementations] was "best" and I use both in different parts of code I work on. However, my view is irrelevant to my initial comment and the lack-luster claim this answer makes. '**There is no evidence provided in this response to support "design-wise, approach 2 is the correct way".**' (Your answer, as it is currently written, is *not* about a public field vs. a property as the last comment tries to muddle in, and the claim which I am alleging is unfounded therein is strictly about approach #2 vs approach #1 which are *both properties*.)

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about different things here.

A. This is a property that will ALWAYS return the hardcoded string value. Meaning that the way you have it written does not let you change that value under any circumstances.

B. With this implementation code, outside your class can never change the value via the MyProperty getter. However, code from within your class can change the value by changing the myString variable.

Answer (score 0):

With backed field you can change the property value from within the class by changing the field. That's the main difference.

If you need your property to be really read only you can add readonly modifier to the field, and it will be more like your first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes C# has many ways of doing things.  However, your code really doesn't show the intent that the property is `readonly`.  For something like this I would use constant.

```
public const string MyProperty = "my string";
```

If the property is read only to the outside world, but is manipulated privately by the class, then I suggest:

```
public string MyProperty { get; private set; }
```